# Android Transition ChangeBounds not working with different size

Tags: android

I use TransitionManager.go to switch between smallScene and expandScene. The width of smallScene=100dp, the width of expandScene=200dp, and the height are consistent. The problem now is that the animation from smallScene to expandScene takes effect, but the animation from expandScene to smallScene does not take effect, The code is shown below. Why does switching from expandScene to smallScene animation not take effect?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ActivityMainBinding binding;
  boolean togger = true;
  Scene smallScene;
  Scene expandScene;

  private final Transition mExpandTransition = new TransitionSet().addTransition(new ChangeBounds())
      .setDuration(1000);

  private final Transition mFoldTransition = new TransitionSet().addTransition(new ChangeBounds())
      .setDuration(1000);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    binding.fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
      if (togger) {
        TransitionManager.go(smallScene, mFoldTransition);
      } else {
        TransitionManager.go(expandScene, mExpandTransition);
      }
      togger = !togger;
    });
    init();

  }

  private void init() {
    smallScene =
        Scene.getSceneForLayout(binding.viewcontainer, R.layout.small_view,
            MainActivity.this);
    expandScene =
        Scene.getSceneForLayout(binding.viewcontainer, R.layout.expand_view,
            MainActivity.this);
  }

}
```

```
small_view.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  android:layout_width="100dp"  android:layout_height="100dp"  android:background="#AFB2D1"></LinearLayout>
```

```
expand_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:background="#ff5344">
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried debugging and searching, but couldn't find relevant information. I hope the switching has animation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by setting same id to `expand_view` and `small_view`, I was so stupid